# Angular 9- changing angular material date format in app.module.ts does not change date pickers format in lazy modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my app.module.ts I have changed the format of my angular material date pickers to be-

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'LL',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
    },
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I expected **all** date pickers in my app to be according to the new format, but I saw that date pickers inside lazy modules did not change their format according to the new format.

Any idea why? I put the provider in my app.module because I don't want to include it in every new lazy module that I write.

Comment: Do you have MatNativeDateModule OR MatMomentDateModule in the lazy loaded modules as well?

Comment: I have MatMomentDateModule now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "MAT_DATE_FORMATS" provider in my app.component.ts solved the problem for lazy modules. but I still have to leave this provider in my app.module for an entry component..